# Error - Class Equalizer - Methods getBand() and getBandFreqRange(short band)

Tags: android, equalizer

I don't know more what I can do to solve these problems. I am
implementing a MediaPlayer + Equalizer app. My MediaPlayer works fine,
however, I am having problem with my equalizer: some its methods don't
work.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private Equalizer equalizer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource("/sdcard/titanium.mp3");
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.start();

        equalizer = new Equalizer(0, 0);
        equalizer.setEnabled(true);

        int minEQLevel = equalizer.getBandLevelRange()[0];
        int maxEQLevel = equalizer.getBandLevelRange()[1];

        Log.i("kkk", "Valor de minEQLevel" + minEQLevel);
        Log.i("kkk", "Valor de maxEQLevel" + maxEQLevel);

        short numberOfBand = equalizer.getNumberOfBands();
        Log.i("kkk", "Número de bandas = "+numberOfBand);

            /******From here to down the methods don't work *****/

        try {
                    short band = equalizer.getBand(Integer.valueOf(50000));
            Log.i("kkk", "getBand() = "+band);
            short band = 0;
            //int menor = equalizer.getBandFreqRange(band)[0];
            //int maior = equalizer.getBandFreqRange(band)[1];
            //Log.i("kkk", "Menor = "+menor);
            //Log.i("kkk", "Maior = "+maior);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.i("kkk", "Bad parameter value");
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
            Log.i("kkk", "get parameter() rejected");
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.i("kkk", "get parameter() called in wrong state");
        }


    }

}
```

The follow methods work normally:
getBandLevelRange();
getNumberOfBands();

The follow methods don't work. I get the message error: Bad parameter
value.
getBand();
getBandFreqRange(); this last is commented, but when it isn't also don't work.

In the getBand() method I already tried several parameters values like: 50000, 1000000. Frequency supported at example of the library AudioFx.

Why don't these methods work??? Did I forgive to setup anything???

tks.

Comment: e.printstacktrace and post the result here

Comment: oh, and, define "don't work"? (you probably are alone in your own head, it's not easy to guess what you mean by that)

Comment: @njzk2 I think that errors are because i am using cyanogen mod im my test device. I'll test in others devices with original rom and I post here the results. tks

Comment: why do you use `Integer.valueOf(50000)` ?

Comment: because I was getting error using only short band = equalizer.getBand(50000), so I tried to use Integer.valueOf().

Comment: @njzk2 I tested in a device with original ROM e my code works fine. I'm going to open another topic to verify why equalizer.getBandFreqRange(numberOfBands-1)[1] return me always 1.